# Dynamic hyperlink that vlookups a cell value and finds the corresponding ID from an array to input into the URL

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to VLOOKUP the cell.value in this case and match it to the ID in column R:R. Column Q:Q is where the cell.value can be found.

The cell.value works and pulls the info. I can't get it to vlookup.

```vb
Public Sub Login_To_Hyperlink()
    Dim VBAIDPull As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ID As String
    
    Set VBAIDPull = Workbooks("testupdated.xlsm").Sheets("Overview").Range("Q2:Q250,R2:R250")

    ID = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, VBAIDPull, 2, False)

    For Each Cell In Range("A2:A250")
        If Cell <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, _
            Address:=Cell.Value, _
            ScreenTip:=ID, _
            TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `"Q2:Q,R2:R"` is not a valid range reference. If you have a starting row (2), you need an ending row.

Comment: ty!!! now its giving me Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Likely you want the `ID = Application.WorksheetFunction...` inside the loop.

Comment: Hmmm all the other errors all set now just showing error 1104 unable to get vlookup property of the worksheetfunctionclass

Comment: That means that `Cell.Value` was not found in Q2:Q250 on the Overview sheet.

Comment: `Range("Q2:R250")` not `Range("Q2:Q250,R2:R250")`

Comment: You're calling `VLookup(Cell.Value,...` before you've set `Cell` to anything.

Answer (score 0):

This might be close what you want:

```vb
Public Sub Login_To_Hyperlink()
    Dim VBAIDPull As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range, ID As Variant 'not string
    
    'you can use ThisWorkbook.Sheets() if your table's in the same workbook as your code
    Set VBAIDPull = Workbooks("testupdated.xlsm").Sheets("Overview").Range("Q2:R250")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each Cell In ws.Range("A2:A250").Cells
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            ID = Application.VLookup(Cell.Value, VBAIDPull, 2, False)
            If Not IsError(ID) Then 'got a match?
                ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, _
                    Address:=Cell.Value, _
                    ScreenTip:=ID, _
                    TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value
            End If 'got a match
        End If     'cell has value
    Next Cell
End Sub
```